# Batch script skipping blank entries in a .CSV when delim is ','

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a .CSV that I am trying to sort through to create another file from the data, but when I run it through, it skips blank entries. For example, if a line is 
`value,value,value,,,value`
and I try to get the 4th column, it would spit out 6th. Presumably because it is the next valid value. I don't want it to skip the blank entry as it can mess up the tables I'm trying to make. Anyone know how to resolve this? (Any tips are welcome as I suck at batch scripts)

Here is my script:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 delims=," %%a in (file.csv) DO (
    echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n
)
pause
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the standard behaviour of the FOR/F loop, consecutive delims only used as one delimiter.
But you can use a workaround with a second FOR/F.
Prefix each column with another character, split the line at the delim and remove the prefix.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%L in (test.bat) DO (
    set "line=%%L,,,,,,,,"
    set "line=#!line:,=,#!"
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=," %%a in ("!line!") DO (
        set "param1=%%a"
        set "param2=%%b"
        set "param3=%%c"
        set "param4=%%d"
        set "param1=!param1:~1!"
        set "param2=!param2:~1!"
        set "param3=!param3:~1!"
        set "param4=!param4:~1!"
        echo !param1! !param2! !param3! !param4!
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115) already mentiones in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557532), `for /F` treats consecutive delimiters as one. To avoid that, you could replace each delimiter `,` by `","` and enclose each full line by `""`, so each field appears as being enclosed within `""`, which can easily be removed finally by the `~` modifier of the `for /F` variable; so there is no need to do any more string manipulations (like sub-string expansion) later on:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%# in ("file.csv") do (
    set "LINE=%%#"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in (^""!LINE:,="^,"!"^") do (
        endlocal
        echo Field 1: %%~A
        echo Field 2: %%~B
        echo Field 3: %%~C
        echo Field 4: %%~D
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

This might not work properly if the data contain `,` characters by themselves (remember that `,` is not considered as delimiter in case a field is enclosed within `""` in the original CSV file).

The toggling of delayed expansion is done to not lose any exclamation marks in the data.