# Batch how to read empty tokens

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have the next batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set lastpart=

for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %%f in (test.csv) do (
set lastPart= %%f
echo !lastPart!
pause
)
```

And the test.csv:

```
a1,,a3,,a5
b1,b2,b3,b4,b5
,,c3,,
,d2,,d4,
,,,,
```

My real output is: a3,b2,d2.
Output I need: empty, b2, empty, d2, empty. 
The problem is that de loop not read empty tokens. Is there a property or something so the loop not avoid empty tokens? The loop always must have 5 tokens per line

Thanks

Comment: Your real output should be **a3**,**b2**,**d4**. They aren't empty tokens, they aren't tokens.

Comment: @Compo I think the OP's real question could be rephrased as "How do you use Batch commands to read CSV files". And CSV files certainly do have empty tokens.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, I would suggest that the CSV has fields, not tokens and that those fields are separated by comma delimiters.

Comment: Use PowerShell. It has built-in commands for handling CSV files. Much, much easier.

Answer (score 3):

`for /F` treats consecutive delimiters as one. To avoid that, you could replace each delimiter `,` by `","` and enclose each full line by `""`, so each item appears as being enclosed within `""`, which can easily be removed finally by the `~` modifier of the `for /F` variable:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "lastpart="

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("test.csv") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set LINE="!LINE:,=","!"
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %%F in ("!LINE!") do (
        endlocal
        set "lastpart=%%~F"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!lastpart!
    )
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

This might not work properly if the data contain `,` characters by themselves (remember that `,` is not considered as delimiter in case a field is enclosed within `""` in the original CSV file).

The toggling of delayed expansion is done to not lose any exclamation marks in the data.

Comment: After I posted my answer, the question has been marked as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17556976), so I copied my answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40729187) and slightly adapted it; I am going to keep this one here until a moderator advices me to delete it...